# setting up a middleware in router.route() in nodejs (express)

Tags: node.js, express

what I want it to do.

```
 router.post('/xxxx', authorize , xxxx);

  function authorize(req, res, next)
   {
    if(xxx)
        res.send(500);
    else
     next(); 
   }
```

I want to check for session in each route.
But since the routers are written in this way.

```
router.route('/xxx/xxxx').post(function(req, res) {
    // blah lah here...
    //
});
```

So how can I set up a middleware that will check for session and I wanted to make things a bit more generic and wanted to have a single authorize function doing a single thing instead of checking in every request.Any suggestions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Define a middlware function before you define / include your routes, this will avoid you checking for a valid session in every route. See code below for an example on how to do this.

If some routes are public, i.e. they do not require a user to have a valid session then define these BEFORE you 'use' your middlware function

```
var app = require("express")();

//This is the middleware function which will be called before any routes get hit which are defined after this point, i.e. in your index.js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  var authorised = false;
  //Here you would check for the user being authenticated

  //Unsure how you're actually checking this, so some psuedo code below
  if (authorised) {
    //Stop the user progressing any further
    return res.status(403).send("Unauthorised!");
  }
  else {
    //Carry on with the request chain
    next();
  }
});

//Define/include your controllers
```

As per your comment, you have two choices with regards to having this middleware affect only some routes, see two examples below.

**Option 1** - Declare your specific routes before the middleware.

```
app.post("/auth/signup", function (req, res, next) { ... });
app.post("/auth/forgotpassword", function (req, res, next) { ... });

//Any routes defined above this point will not have the middleware executed before they are hit.

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //Check for session (See the middlware function above)
    next();
});

//Any routes defined after this point will have the middlware executed before they get hit

//The middlware function will get hit before this is executed
app.get("/someauthorisedrouter", function (req, res, next) { ... });
```

**Option 2** Define your middlware function somewhere and require it where needed

/middleware.js

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    //Do your session checking...
    next();
};
```

Now you can require it wherever you want it.

/index.js

```
var session_check = require("./middleware"),
    router = require("express").Router();

//No need to include the middlware on this function
router.post("/signup", function (req, res, next) {...});

//The session middleware will be invoked before the route logic is executed..
router.get("/someprivatecontent", session_check, function (req, res, next) { ... });


module.exports = router;
```

Hope that gives you a general idea of how you can achieve this feature.

Comment: hey lee that will solve but it will apply to all the routes I guess which is not exactly what I want, I wanted to add it to specific routes leaving behind something like signup, forget password etc.

Comment: You have two choices there really. You could define your signup and forget password routes BEFORE you declare the middleware, or you could pass the middleware function to all of the routes you want it to be used on.

Comment: No problem, I have updated my answer to give you a couple of examples. They are semi pseudo code mind, i.e. missing some requires, etc. Have fun!

Answer (score 6):

Express routers have a neat [`use()` function](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use) that lets you define [middleware](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/middleware) for all routes. `router.use('/xxxxx', authorize); router.post('/xxxx', 'xxxx');` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Middleware: 
sampleMiddleware.js

```
export const verifyUser = (req, res, next) => {
   console.log('Verified')
   next();
}
```

Routes

```
import express from 'express';
import { verifyUser } from './sampleMiddleware.js';

const userRoutes = express.Router();

userRoutes.route('/update').put(verifyUser, async function(){
     //write your function heere
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use it the following way

```
router.use(
   routerLevelMiddleware
);

router.route('/endpoint1').get(myEndpoint1Function());
router.route('/endpoint2').get(myEndpoint2Function());
```

OR

```
router.route('/').get(routerLevelMiddleware(), myEndpoint1Function());
```

Answer (score -1):

You've probably gotten the answer you need but I'll still drop this

```
router.route('/xxx/xxxx').get(authorize, function(req, res) {...});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: TypeError: Router.route(...).route is not a function