# Basic auth in node js

Tags: node.js, basic-authentication

I am writing a post request with basic auth in node js.I am trying to hit API without authorization field in header, still I am not getting any error.

```
subscriptionRouter.route('/subscriptions')
  .post((req, res) => {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));

    if (!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.indexOf('Basic ') === -1) {
      res.status(401).json({ message: 'Missing Authorization Header' });
    }

    const base64Credentials =  req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

    const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('ascii');

    if(credentials == 'GsubNode:WelcomeNode@123'){
      console.log(req.body);
      var msgId = putMessageSync(req.body);

      let responseJSON = {};
      
      if (msgId == "") {
        responseJSON.statusCode = 400;
        responseJSON.statusDesc = "Bad Request";
        responseJSON.msgId = msgId;
      }
      else {
        responseJSON.statusCode = 200;
        responseJSON.statusDesc = "Posted";
        responseJSON.MsgId = msgId;
      }

      res.json(responseJSON);
    }
    else{
      res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid Authentication Credentials' });
    }
    
  })
```

Comment: Are you using express here? Would you try to return inside the if statement, as sending the response does not stop execution of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a middleware, first declare the function:

```
function authenticate(req, res, next){
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const base64Credentials = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    if( base64Credentials == null ) return res.sendStatus(401)
    if(credentials == 'GsubNode:WelcomeNode@123'){
        next()
    }
}
```

Then you'd specify the middleware for each path you'd like to authenticate and run the rest of your code for the api call (using express) like:

```
express.post('/subscriptions', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
      var msgId = putMessageSync(req.body);

      let responseJSON = {};
      
      if (msgId == "") {
        responseJSON.statusCode = 400;
        responseJSON.statusDesc = "Bad Request";
        responseJSON.msgId = msgId;
      }
      else {
        responseJSON.statusCode = 200;
        responseJSON.statusDesc = "Posted";
        responseJSON.MsgId = msgId;
      }

      res.json(responseJSON);
});
```

EDIT: The answer to this post elaborates on routers and middleware: [setting up a middleware in router.route() in nodejs (express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263787/setting-up-a-middleware-in-router-route-in-nodejs-express)